Why can't I post an image to the Image Block feed on Adafruit?
I am using an AI Thinker Cam32 to subscribe and publish to my Adafruit.io account.  I am using Adafruit_MQTT.h and Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h libraries. I am using ArduinoIDE on a MacBook Pro running MacOS Sequoia 15.1.
I am able to publish a simple uint32_t x=1 and Subscribe to two feeds.  I can get the value of those feeds and turn on and off pins on the ESP32 depending on the values from one feed.  From the other feed I would like to take a photo and Publish the Image to the Image Block feed when the subscribed feed is a certain value.
I have been able to Publish an image from the ESP32 using PubSubClient.h library but would prefer using the Adafruit libraries.
Here is the code I use to connect to the Wifi, my Adafruit account, and Subscribe and Publish to that account.
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <WiFiManager.h> 
//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"
#include "src/OV2640.h"
#include <string.h>
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
#include <base64.h>
/************************* WiFi Access Point *********************************/

/************************* Adafruit.io Setup *********************************/

#define AIO_SERVER      "io.adafruit.com"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT  1883                   // 8883 for MQTTS
#define AIO_USERNAME    "VVVVVVV"
#define AIO_KEY         "aioXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0eL"
#define LED 14
int tripper = 1;
OV2640 cam;

/************ Global State (you don't need to change this!) ******************/

// Create an ESP8266 WiFiClient class to connect to the MQTT server.
WiFiClient client;
// or... use WiFiFlientSecure for SSL
//WiFiClientSecure client;

// Setup the MQTT client class by passing in the WiFi client and MQTT server and login details.
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);

/****************************** Feeds ***************************************/

// Setup a feed called 'photocell' for publishing.
// Notice MQTT paths for AIO follow the form: <username>/feeds/<feedname>
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish camera1 = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/camera");
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish wifi = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/wifi-connection");


// Setup a feed called 'onoff' for subscribing to changes.
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe trip2 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/video");

/*************************** Error Reporting *********************************/

Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe errors = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/errors");
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe throttle = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/throttle");

/*************************** Sketch Code ************************************/

// Bug workaround for Arduino 1.6.6, it seems to need a function declaration
// for some reason (only affects ESP8266, likely an arduino-builder bug).
void MQTT_connect();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("Adafruit MQTT demo"));

  // Connect to WiFi access point.
 WiFiManager wifiManager;
 wifiManager.autoConnect("LEVEL2");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Setup MQTT subscription for onoff feed
  mqtt.subscribe(&trip2);

  // Setup MQTT subscriptions for throttle & error messages
  mqtt.subscribe(&throttle);
  mqtt.subscribe(&errors);

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  
  config.fb_count = 1;

  cam.init(config);
}

uint32_t x=1;

void loop() {
  
  MQTT_connect();

  Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe *subscription;
  while ((subscription = mqtt.readSubscription(5000))) {
    if (subscription == &trip2) {
      Serial.print(F("Got onoff: "));
      Serial.println((char *)trip2.lastread);
    uint16_t sliderval = atoi((char *)trip2.lastread);
      if((sliderval ==0)&&(tripper == 1)){
        camera_fb_t *fb = NULL;
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    //delay(500);

    if (!fb)
    {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      return;
      
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Camera Captured");
      
    }

   //ADAFRUIT REQUIRES IMAGES BE BASE64 ENCODED

     size_t size = fb->len;
   String buffer = base64::encode((uint8_t *)fb->buf, fb->len);
    //String buffer = base64::encode(fb->buf, fb->len);
    Serial.println(buffer);

    unsigned int length();
    Serial.println("Buffer Length: ");
    Serial.print(buffer.length());
    Serial.println("");

    if (buffer.length() > 102400)
    {
      Serial.println("Image size too big");
      return;
    }
    
Serial.print(F("\nSending camera1 val"));
 
  Serial.print(buffer.c_str());
 Serial.print("...");
 
 //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES AND RESTARTS
 
  if (! camera1.publish(buffer.c_str())) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }
        tripper = 2;
         buffer = "";
      }
     
      else if((sliderval == 8)&&(tripper == 2)){
       
        tripper = 1;
      }
    } else if(subscription == &errors) {
      Serial.print(F("ERROR: "));
      Serial.println((char *)errors.lastread);
    } else if(subscription == &throttle) {
      Serial.println((char *)throttle.lastread);
    }
  }
  
  // Now we can publish stuff! 01
  Serial.print(F("\nSending wifi val "));
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print("...");
  if (! wifi.publish(x)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }



delay(5000);
 
}

// Function to connect and reconnect as necessary to the MQTT server.
// Should be called in the loop function and it will take care if connecting.
void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  uint8_t retries = 3;
  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
       Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
       Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
       mqtt.disconnect();
       delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
       retries--;
       if (retries == 0) {
         // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
         while (1);
       }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
  
}

Here is the log crash report.
Sending wifi val 1...OK!
Got onoff: 0
Camera Captured
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/2wBDAAoHCAkIBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx8WFxIZJCAmJiQgIyIoLToxKCs2KyIjMkQzNjs9QEFAJzBHTEY/Szo/QD7/2wBDAQsLCw8NDx0QEB0+KSMpPj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj7/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1E I removed most of the stream to shorten the post. I can put the whole thing in if you need it //Z
Buffer Length: 
27712

Sending camera1 val/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/2wBDAAoHCAkIBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx8WFxIZJCAmJiQgIyIoLToxKCs2KyIjMkQzNjs9QEFAJzBHTEY/Szo/QD7/ again I shortened the post  //Z...



Backtrace: 0x6a537667:0x3ffbed0c |<-CORRUPTED




Backtrace: 0x00667fbd:0x00667fc0 |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: 474b6a6f54754d5a

Re-entered core dump! Exception happened during core dump!
Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13964
load:0x40080400,len:3600
entry 0x400805f0
Adafruit MQTT demo

I have tried different things to get the post to work but to no avail.  If I change the part where it crashes to
if (! camera1.publish(x)) {
Serial.println(F("Failed"));
} else {
Serial.println(F("OK!"));
}

the program doesn't crash, the OK! is printed out and the block feed says it was updated but with no imaged displayed.
I don't know what is corrupted since I have tried three different CAM32 with the same results.  Do I need to use different code to do the publishing of an image?  Does the Adafruit_MQTT.h library allow for the Publishing of images?
I would really appreciate any and all help anyone could give me.
Thanks

I see the output for the ESP8266 12e is 12mA per pin where the output for the ESP32 CAM is 20mA per pin.  I don't think this should cause a problem.  Maybe if it were less but not if it is more mAs  What do you think.

Got this to work.  Changed IO12 pin for IO14pin.  Also rebuilt a whole new board to make sure all components were good.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for all the input.
